# How could I implement something like "thesheepmarket" with CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make something similar to thesheepmarket.com in how they have a bunch of small images together, and when you scroll over one it pops out like that so you can see the image larger.

I would like to do this with CSS/JS.

Any help would be great.

So I can basically do everything, except I am not sure how to make the div popup a bit below:

```
#test {
height: 10px;
background: red;
width: 10px;
font-size: 1px; /* IE 6 */
}

#test:hover {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}

$('#test').hover(function() {
console.log('hoved');
```

});

I am basically just looking for the best way to make the div popup below the one that it is currently hovering over.

Comment: Look at the source code for how thesheepmarket.com did it. This question shows a distinct lack of effort

Comment: Unfortunately it is implemented in flash.

Answer (score 1):

consider using something like this plugin:
http://dropthebit.com/demos/photobox/

From the Plugin website:

**HTML**

```
<div id='gallery'>
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image1_large.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image1_small.jpg" title="photo1 title">
</a>
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image2_large.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image2_small.jpg" alt="photo2 title">
</a>
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image3_large.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image3_small.jpg" title="photo3 title">
</a>
<a href="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image4_large.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.somedomain.com/images/image4_small.jpg" alt="photo4 title" data-pb-captionLink='Google website[www.google.com]'>
</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W3OQgh_h4U4" rel="video">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/W3OQgh_h4U4/0.jpg" title="PEOPLE ARE AWESOME 2013 FULL HD ">
</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
// applying photobox on a `gallery` element which has lots of thumbnails links. Passing options object as well:
//-----------------------------------------------
$('#gallery').photobox('a',{ time:0 });

// using a callback and a fancier selector
//----------------------------------------------
$('#gallery').photobox('li > a.family',{ time:0 }), callback);
function callback(){
   console.log('image has been loaded');
}

// destroy the plugin on a certain gallery:
//-----------------------------------------------
$('#gallery').data('_photobox').destroy();

// re-initialize the photbox DOM (does what Document ready does)
//-----------------------------------------------
$('#gallery').photobox('prepareDOM');
</script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: as you can see the question is due to lack of searching and laziness , so i cant afford any other information , i would rather delete my answer.